# Clang optimization pragma

Tags: c, clang

I'm trying to compile a specific function without any optimizations. I'm using `clang` with this `--version` output:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

I tried to use `#pragma clang optimize off` to turn optimizations off. Here is my code example:

```
#pragma clang optimize off

int main()
{
    int x = 777;
    x = 555;
    x = 888;
    x = 999;

    printf("%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
#pragma clang optimize on
```

But when i checked the output of `clang -S -O3` redundant assignments is gone. Using `__attribute__(optnone)` doesn't work too. By the way when i compile without `-O3` option redundant assignments is here.

What am i doing wrong?

**UPD:** Compiling with `-Wall` gives

```
opt.c:13:15: warning: unknown pragma ignored [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma clang optimize off
```

Comment: One of the comments in the possible duplicate suggests this might be a bug with apple clang. Furthermore, if you'd like to keep the redundant assignments, consider declaring `x` as `volatile int x`.

Comment: @Lanting thx, looks like i have to use `volatile` keyword.